# Trying to iterate through rows in a pandas dataframe, grab the list of urls in each row, and extract emails using scrapy

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, scrapy

I wrote some code that adds lists of relevant urls to a row in a pandas dataframe. Now, I'm trying to iterate through those lists and search each one for email addresses. Here's what I have thus far:

```
import requests, random, traceback, logging, os, re
from lxml.html import fromstring
from itertools import cycle
import pandas as pd
from googlesearch import search
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy.linkextractors.lxmlhtml import LxmlLinkExtractor

# # FOR JUPYTER NOTEBOOKS:
logging.getLogger('scrapy').propagate = False


# PULL IN A LIST:
df = pd.read_csv('example.csv')
df = df.drop_duplicates()

# GET URLS FROM LIST:
def get_urls(tag, n, language):
    urls = [url for url in search(tag, stop=n, lang=language)][:n]
    return urls

# SCRAPE URLS FROM LIST
scrape_urls = lambda x: [get_urls(x, 10, 'en') for x in df.Names]
df['urls'] = df.apply(scrape_urls)
```

Which returns:

```
   Names           urls
0  Turner Construction [https://www.turnerconstruction.com/, http://w...
1  McCarthy Holdings   [https://www.mccarthy.com/, https://www.mccart...
2  Brasfield & Gorrie  [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brasfield_%26_G...
3  Skanska USA         [https://www.usa.skanska.com/, https://www.usa...
4  DPR Construction    [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DPR_Constructio...
```

Running `df.urls[0]` shows the data a little better:

```
['https://www.turnerconstruction.com/',
 'http://www.turnerconstruction.com/careers',
 'http://www.turnerconstruction.com/about-us',
 'http://www.turnerconstruction.com/office-network',
 'http://www.turnerconstruction.com/office-network/new-york',
 'http://www.turnerconstruction.com/careers/jobs',
 'http://www.turnerconstruction.com/careers/experienced',
 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turner_Construction',
 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turner_Construction#History',
 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turner_Construction#Early_years']
```

There is a list of 10 urls for each name in Names.

Now, I'm trying to run a scrapy spider that searches those urls for emails, ensuring that it looks for additional links inside 'urls' as well:

```
# CRATE A SCRAPY SPIDER THAT SEARCHES URLS FOR LINKS AND GOES THROUGH THEM FOR EMAILS
class MailSpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = 'email'

    def parse(self, response):
#         check for new URLs inside a source
        links = LxmlLinkExtractor(allow=()).extract_links(response)
        links = [str(link.url) for link in links]
        links.append(str(response.url))

        for link in links:
#             send links from one parse method to another
            yield scrapy.Request(url=link, callback=self.parse_link) 

    def parse_link(self, response):

        for word in self.reject:
            if word in str(response.url):
                return

        html_text = str(response.text)
#         regex expression to search for emails
        mail_list = re.findall('\w+@\w+\.{1}\w+', html_text)

        dic = {'name': name, 'link': str(response.url), 'email': mail_list}
        df2 = pd.DataFrame(dic)

        df2.to_csv(self.path, mode='a', header=False)
        df2.to_csv(self.path, mode='a', header=False)
```

Then, I'm defining a functions that should get emails (`get_info`), ask the user if they'd like to create a file with those emails added (`ask_user`), and then create that file (`create_file`):

```
def ask_user(question):
    response = input(question + ' y/n' + '\n')
    if response == 'y':
        return True
    else:
        return False

def create_file(path):
    response = False
    if os.path.exists(path):
        response = ask_user('File already exists, replace?')
        if response == False: return 

    with open(path, 'wb') as file: 
        file.close()

def get_info(tag, path, reject=[]):

    create_file(path)
    df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['name', 'urls', 'email'], index=[0])
    df2.to_csv(path, mode='w', header=True)

    print('Collecting urls...')
    url_lists = df['urls']

    print('Searching for emails...')
    process = CrawlerProcess({'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
    process.crawl(MailSpider, start_urls=url_lists, path=path, reject=reject)
    process.start()

    print('Cleaning emails...')
    df2 = pd.read_csv(path, index_col=0)
    df2.columns = ['name', 'links', 'email']
    df2 = df.drop_duplicates(subset='email')
    df2 = df.reset_index(drop=True)
    df2.to_csv(path, mode='w', header=True)

    return df2
```

Lastly, I'm calling it all by identifying a list of `bad_words` to eliminate from search, then calling `get_info`:

```
bad_words = ['facebook', 'instagram', 'youtube', 'twitter', 'wiki']
df = get_info(df['urls'], 'company_info.csv', reject=bad_words)
```

I'm not really sure what I'm doing wrong, but I know there has to be a better way of doing this. Please tell me what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: By "doing wrong" do mean that you get an error? Or that you just want to know how to optimise the code?

Comment: This thread might have the answer you're looking for. https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/748/is-there-a-git-for-data